# Istio: AuthorizationPolicy executed before RequestAuthentication?

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I'd like to understand in which order `RequestAuthentications` and `AuthorizationPolicies` are executed for an `istio-ingressgateway`.

In a PoC, I'm defining the following `RequestAuthentication` and `AuthorizationPolicy` for the istio-ingressgateway, where the `AuthorizationPolicy` uses the `CUSTOM` action (external authorizer):

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata: 
  name: ingress-reguest-authentication
  namespace: istio-system
spec: 
  jwtRules: 
    - 
      issuer: "https://<my-issuer>"
      jwksUri: "https://<my-issuer>/oauth2/jwks"
      forwardOriginalToken: true
      outputPayloadToHeader: x-forwarded-jwt-payload
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: ingress-ext-authz
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  action: CUSTOM
  provider:
    name: ext-authz-http
  rules: [{}]
```

With the `RequestPolicy` I'd like to let Istio handle the basic token validation *before* the external authorizer performs additional checks, for which Istio doesn't provide configuration (in my case I want to verify that the mTLS client certificate and JWT token for an incoming request match according to [RFC 8705](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8705)). Since I don't want to validate the token again in the external authorizer, I'm using the `outputPayloadToHeader` to forward the payload of the validated JWT.

However, to my surprise, it looks like the external authorizer is actually called before the request authentication happens:

- The `x-forwarded-jwt-payload` header defined in the `RequestAuthentication` is not arriving at the external authorizer (I ended up using the Authorization header instead to extract the JWT payload myself).
- A request with an *expired* access token that also didn't match the used client cert resulted in a deny response from the external authorizer instead of the expired token being rejected by the request authentication before.

This is not what I had expected, given that `ALLOW`/`DENY` actions for authorization policies support rules which inspect JWT claims, which I assumed would be evaluated for an already validated JWT.

Is this the order in which Istio processes `RequestAuthentication` and `AuthorizationPolicy` in general or is it specific to the `CUSTOM` action?

Or is there simply something wrong in my configuration?

Comment: I suspect that the authentication is handled after any customer/external authorization requests. Take a look at [this](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/security/#implicit-enablement) diagram. Could you enable debug logging for the ingress controller and verify this though? I would think the logging output would prove that theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, what helped to get the order right was configuring the external authorizer through an envoy filter that is plugged into the `http_connection_manager` filter chain right before http router filter.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: ingress-ext-authz
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            subFilter:
              name: envoy.filters.http.router
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
        name: envoy.filters.http.ext_authz
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthz
          failureModeAllow: false
          httpService:
            serverUri:
              cluster: outbound|8000||ext-authz.default.svc.cluster.local
              timeout: 1s
              uri: http://ext-authz.default.svc.cluster.local
            authorizationRequest:
              allowedHeaders:
                patterns:
                  - exact: x-forwarded-jwt-payload
                  - exact: x-forwarded-client-cert
```